# Is there a way to create a kissing people curve using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to create custom graphs using ggplot2, for example I want to create a graph of kissing people.
Simple variant
[image]
Not completely, but partially, I was able to reproduce it, everything except for the "lines of the eyes" is not clear how to mark them

But how to make a more complex graph of kissing people. In general, is it possible to somehow approximate such a curve, more voluminou?

[image]

thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can draw any lines you like in ggplot using geom_path. The difficulty is in generating the coordinates representing these lines. They are unlikely to be described by a nice compact mathematical expression, so you would need to either draw the image in a vector art program and extract the co-ordinates, or use trial and error to draw what you want manually. It's not really clear what you are asking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps not what you are looking for, but if you have already got the image, and want to reproduce it in ggplot, then you can use the following method:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magick)
library(terra)

# read image
im <- image_read("./data/kiss_1.png")
# conver to black/white image
im2 <- im %>%
  image_quantize(
    max = 2,
    colorspace = "gray" )
# get a matrix of the pixel-colors
m <- as.raster(im2) %>% as.matrix()
# extract coordinates of the black pixels
df <- as.data.frame(which(m == "#000000ff", arr.ind=TRUE))
df$row <- df$row * -1
# plot point
ggplot(df, aes(x = col, y = row)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

[image]